# Fetch data from same table with different condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have one table name as user(id,Name,Status,joined_date).

## usertable

```
 id | Name | status | joined_date

 -------------------------------------
 1  | TDS  |  0      |      2014-10-16 

 2  | TDS  |  1      |      2014-10-11 

 3  | VAT  |  0      |      2014-10-11 

 4  | IT   |  0      |      2014-10-11 

 5  | IT   |  1      |      2014-10-11

 6  | TDS  |  0      |      2014-10-16 

 7  | TDS  |  1      |      2014-10-30 

 8  | VAT  |  0      |      2014-11-01 

 9  | IT   |  0      |      2014-10-07 

10  | IT   |  1      |      2014-10-11
```

In my result i need count of Name in  current month and count of name in current month with status is one. For each name the both result in same row.

## expected result

```
Name    |   current_month | current_month_ststus_1             

-----------------------------------------------------

  VAT   |         2       |            0 

  IT    |         4       |            1

 TDS    |         4       |            2
```

I am bit confuse for this query for last days.Please help me if possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: pl provide create table query also

Comment: VAT spread in two months,what does current month mean?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Even I am confused..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SELECT name,count(status) as current_month, sum(status) as
>   current_month_status FROM `usertable` WHERE month(joined_date) =
>   MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY name

Comment: You should include year in your where clause or else the same month from separate years will get grouped together. (See my answer for example)

Answer (score 0):

if the status only allow 0,1,

you can get the result like this.

> `select count(Name) as current_month,sum(status) as current_month_status_1 from table group by currentmonth`

Answer (score 0):

Eh, I'm thinking of something like the following.

```
SELECT
    Name,
    COUNT(Status) AS current_month,
    SUM(status) AS current_month_status_1
FROM
    Usertable
WHERE
        MONTH(joined_date) = MONTH(NOW())
    AND YEAR(joined_date) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY
    Name,
    YEAR(joined_date),
    MONTH(joined_date)
```

This assumes that status can only be one or zero.

Answer (score 0):

select category_id,(select count(id) from category_images where delete_status='1'and

id = o.id group by category_id) as delete1,

(select count(id) from ategory_images where delete_status='0' and id = o.id group by

category_id)as delete2  from category_images o

I go with category_id you have to go with name field okay i hope this will solve your problem